# Writing a Groovy Script to execute this command to PostgresDB

Tags: sql

I currently am using SOAPUI 4.0 Pro to hit a Postgresdb on a specific host.  I have modified my properties file to include port, username, and password and name of database.  Here is my query below:

```
SELECT 
  eis_entity.local_id, 
  eis_trait_instance_history.trait_value,
  eis_identifier_domain.identifier,
  eis_identifier_domain.label
FROM 
  public.eis_entity,
  public.eis_trait_instance_history,
  public.eis_version_label,
  public.eis_identifier_domain
WHERE eis_identifier_domain.eis_identifier_domain_key = eis_entity.eis_identifier_domain_key
  AND eis_entity.eis_entity_key=eis_version_label.eis_entity_key  
  AND eis_version_label.eis_version_label_key=eis_trait_instance_history.eis_version_label_key
  AND eis_trait_instance_history.trait_value='<name of patient>';
```

How would I create a groovy script for the query above?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can pick up Groovy SQL basics and have a handle on a `sql` instance...

```
sql = Sql.newInstance(...)
def List eisEntityList = sql.rows("""
    SELECT eis_entity.local_id,
           eis_trait_instance_history.trait_value,
           eis_identifier_domain.identifier,
           eis_identifier_domain.label
    FROM public.eis_entity,
         public.eis_trait_instance_history,
         public.eis_version_label,
         public.eis_identifier_domain
    WHERE eis_identifier_domain.eis_identifier_domain_key = eis_entity.eis_identifier_domain_key
          AND eis_entity.eis_entity_key = eis_version_label.eis_entity_key
          AND eis_version_label.eis_version_label_key = eis_trait_instance_history.eis_version_label_key
          AND eis_trait_instance_history.trait_value = ''
""")

if (eisEntityList?.size() > 0) {

    eisEntityList.each {
        // do something with each item...
    }
}
```